# Windows Form Timer Vs Single Thread Application

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading, timer

I have this windows form, `timer1` is enabled and it's interval is set to 2000 ms.
why the form shows a message box every 2 second? I mean when the first time timer tick called the UI thread will wait until the OK button pressed, so if I don't push the button so there should not another message box appear. but it appears! why?

I know that timer works on it's own thread, and the timer invokes the timer_tick function on it's intervals, the question is how another messagebox is shown when UI thread is blocked on mbox.show()?

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you used MessageBox.  It is a modal dialog that pumps a message loop.  So all the normal Windows notifications are still delivered.  Like paint events.  The only thing it blocks is user input notifications, mouse and keyboard.  But *not* a timer message.  The Form.ShowDialog() method works this way as well.

You will have to disable the timer yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Timer creates own worker thread which is not wait for OK button as it does main UI thread.

Try out following, does it work? (can't check it now sorry)

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{       
    timer.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show("test");     
    timer.Start();
}
```

**EDIT:** Answering to the question in comments

> so if main UI thread stopped at mbox.Show() why another messagebox
>   displayed?

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/560028/485076)

> MessageBox.Show will show UI on the thread it is called from. If there
>   isn't already a message pump running on the thread it will setup a
>   temporary one in order to function. It will tear it down after the
>   Show call completes

Comment: so if main UI thread stopped at mbox.Show() why another messagebox displayed?

Answer (score 0):

The timer works on it's own thread not on the UI thread so it is not blocked by the message box dialogue.

You could have a look using reflector to see how it works.

Comment: I know that timer works on it's own thread, and the timer invokes the timer_tick function on it's intervals, the question is how another messagebox is shown when UI thread is blocked on mbox.show()?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to stop the timer when the message box is shown and restart it when the box closes:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.timer.Stop();
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("test");
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        this.timer.Start();
    }
}
```