# Windows.Forms.Timer OR System.Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have an application that runs many threads. Each thread should have a timer that checks for something in that thread's scope. My question is: Which timer I should use and what is the difference between them?

Comment: I believe the Windows.Forms.Timer may only run on the UI thread.  I know that it is inaccurate and will drift.  Based on your question I would look into the TPL (Task Parallel Libray).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This article provides an excellent comparison and should contain the information you need: [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](https://web.archive.org/web/20150329101415/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx):

```
                                    Windows.Forms  System.Timers         System.Threading 
Timer event runs on what thread?    UI thread      UI or worker thread   Worker thread 
Instances are thread safe?          No             Yes                   No 
Familiar/intuitive object model?    Yes            Yes                   No 
Requires Windows Forms?             Yes            No                    No 
Metronome-quality beat?             No             Yes*                  Yes* 
Timer event supports state object?  No             No                    Yes 
Initial timer event schedulable?    No             No                    Yes 
Class supports inheritance?         Yes            Yes                   No
```

* Depending on the availability of system resources (for example, worker threads)