# How to run a timer in C# only once?

Tags: c#

I want a timer in C# to destroy itself once it has executed. How might I achieve this?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExecuteIn(2000, () =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("fsdfs");   
    });           
}

public static void ExecuteIn(int milliseconds, Action action)
{
    var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Tick += (s, e) => { action(); };
    timer.Interval = milliseconds;
    timer.Start();

    //timer.Stop();
}
```

I want this message box to show only once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try stopping the timer as soon as it enters Tick:

```
timer.Tick += (s, e) => 
{ 
  ((System.Windows.Forms.Timer)s).Stop(); //s is the Timer
  action(); 
};
```

Comment: AutoReset is a better solution

Answer (score 33):

use the Timer.AutoReset property:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset(v=vs.110).aspx

i.e:

```cs
System.Timers.Timer runonce=new System.Timers.Timer(milliseconds);
runonce.Elapsed+=(s, e) => { action(); };
runonce.AutoReset=false;
runonce.Start();
```

To stop or dispose the Timer in the Tick method is unstable as far as I am concerned

EDIT: This doesn't work with System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Comment: For a difference between timers https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532859/1737819

Answer (score 17):

My favorite technique is to do this...

```
Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000))
    .ContinueWith(task => MessageBox.Show("fsdfs"));
```

Comment: this is better than a timer by far.

Comment: Use `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskEx` instead of `Task` if you target .NET 4.0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041478/await-async-taskex/35041622#35041622

Answer (score 0):

add

```
timer.Tick += (s, e) => { timer.Stop() };
```

after

```
timer.Tick += (s, e) => { action(); };
```

Answer (score 0):

Put *timer.Dispose()* it in the method for Tick before the *action* (if the action waits on a user's respose i.e. your MessageBox, then the timer will continue until they've responded).

```
timer.Tick += (s, e) => { timer.Dispose(); action(); };
```

Answer (score 0):

In Intializelayout() write this.

```
this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
this.timer1.Enabled = true;
this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
```

and in form code add this method

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        doaction();
        timer1.Stop();
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
```