# How to create TIMER in a Windows Service (C#) that waits the main method ends

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service

experts!

I'm developing a Windows Service in C#. My problem is my service restarting the timer before the previous operation ends.
For example:

```
timer.Interval = 60000;
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.ImportXML); 
timer.Start();
```

My timer is set to 1 hour. But if my main method (ImportXML) has not yet finished, the timer will restart and start the main method again.

How can I wait my method be finished to start again (restart the timer).

Thank you all!

I tried to search other solutions to use timer waiting my main method ends

Comment: So don't use a timer? Use something like `Task.Delay` with `ContinueWith`. [How to run a timer in C# only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38603299)

Comment: Also, `60000 ms` is one minute, not one hour.

Comment: Also, if you are only doing something once an hour, consider using Windows Task Scheduler instead of a service?

Comment: An import of _one_ xml that takes longer than an hour? Sounds suspicious, but ok. Have you considered PeriodicTimer?

Comment: To ensure that the timer does not restart before the previous operation completes, you can introduce a flag to track the status of the operation. You can set this flag when the operation starts and clear it when the operation completes. Additionally, you can check the flag before restarting the timer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an external bool field to track whether the timer handler is already running or not and exit if the previous one is still running. `TimerHandler` checks if the previous one is still running and if it is it just exits, it will run again on the next interval. The lock is because the handler runs in separate threads so to prevent race conditions with multiple handlers touching the same `_timerHandlerRunning` variable you use a lock so only one can run at a time. Also be sure to dispose the timer when you're done, disposable objects should always be disposed before program exit.

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly object _timerHandlerLock = new object();
    private static bool _timerHandlerRunning;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var timer = new System.Timers.Timer())
        {
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerHandler);
            timer.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();

            timer.Stop();
            timer.Elapsed -= TimerHandler;
        }
    }

    public static void TimerHandler(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter timer handler");
        lock (_timerHandlerLock)
        {
            if (_timerHandlerRunning)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Previous handler still running, returning");
                return;
            }

            _timerHandlerRunning = true;
        }

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Importing xml");
            ImportXML();
        }
        finally
        {
            lock (_timerHandlerLock)
            {
                _timerHandlerRunning = false;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Exiting timer handler");
    }

    public static void ImportXML()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```