# remove Items in ListView by timer C#

Tags: c#, listview, timer

I have a C# ListView with some entrys, a Methode to remove the first entry and a Timer to call this method. My problem is, the timer works well (I checked this with calling a MessageBox) and the remove method wors also well (I checket this by calling this method with a Button and not by the timer). But the timer is still not abel to remove items from my ListView.

My Code:

```
    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        removeItems();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        removeItems();      
    }

    void removeItems()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello from the removeMethod");
        listViewTeam.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    }
```

Both calls of removeItems(); let the messageBox appear but only the Button let also delete the first Item of the listView.

Can someone help ne how I can remove the first Item by a timer?

Comment: Which timer are you using? System.Timer or System.Windows.Forms.Timer? Have you called the Start() method on the timer? EDIT: Just saw you use the System timer. Use the Winforms timer as the others said and call Start()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timer you're using is not thread safe. Instead of using `System.Timer` you should use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` because it automatically runs on the UI thread. Then your code will work perfectly.

Comment: "*The timer you're using is not thread safe*" - wrong, the one you are suggesting isn't.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx *System.Windows.Forms.Timer The timer events raised by this timer class are synchronous with respect to the rest of the code in your Windows Forms app. any code that resides inside a timer event handler (for this type of timer class) is executed using the application's UI thread.*

It is completely thread safe with respect to a windows forms application.

Comment: It's thread safe in a windows forms application when using a single UI thread, yes. `Forms.Timer` is designed *specifically* for a single-threaded environment therefore it's **not** thread safe. You couldn't, for example, use it in a multi-threaded environment. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) itself even states "*The Windows Forms Timer component is single-threaded, and is limited to an accuracy of 55 milliseconds. If you require a multithreaded timer with greater accuracy, use the Timer class in the System.Timers namespace.*".

Comment: visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532850/windows-forms-timer-or-system-threading-timer

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using `System.Timer` which means your `Elapsed` callback may not necessarily be invoked on the UI thread. You can ensure it does by using `Invoke` i.e.

```
if (listViewTeam.InvokeRequired)
{
    listViewTeam.Invoke((MethodDelegate)delegate { listViewTeam.Items.RemoveAt(0); });
}
```

Or even easier set the [SynchronizingObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx) property of your timer to be the form which contains your `ListView` and your code will just work.

Comment: It's far simpler to use the Forms timer as it runs on the UI thread, but this is another solution to call cross-thread.

Comment: It's simpler, but less accurate - it all really depends on the purpose of the timer and what context it's being used in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `delegate` to safely interact with the UI control from a background thread (which is what you are *really* doing when you implement a `Timer`):

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    removeItems();
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    removeItems();      
}

void removeItems()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello from the removeMethod");
    RemoveListViewItem(0);
}

public delegate void InvokeRemoveListViewItem(Int32 ItemIndex);
public void RemoveListViewItem(Int32 ItemIndex)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        try { Invoke(new InvokeRemoveListViewItem(RemoveListViewItem), new Object[] { ItemIndex }); }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //react to the exception you've caught
        }
    }

    listView.RemoveAt(ItemIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like SLC said you need to use BeginInvoke. Personally I have solved it like this

```
  public AddListItem myDelegate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check:

- [Close a MessageBox after several seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522540/close-a-messagebox-after-several-seconds)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19714/Auto-close-message-box
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7968/MessageBox-with-a-timeout-for-NET

Answer (score 0):

```
                               Windows.Forms       System.Timers         System.Threading 
Timer event runs on what thread?    UI thread      UI or worker thread   Worker thread 
Instances are thread safe?          No             Yes                   No 
Familiar/intuitive object model?    Yes            Yes                   No 
Requires Windows Forms?             Yes            No                    No 
Metronome-quality beat?             No             Yes*                  Yes* 
Timer event supports state object?  No             No                    Yes 
Initial timer event schedulable?    No             No                    Yes 
Class supports inheritance?         Yes            Yes                   No

* Depending on the availability of system resources (for example, worker threads)
```

Answer (score -1):

Start the timer first. BUT use the [Windows Forms Timer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)

Your designer class:

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // listBox1
        // 
        this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "q",
        "w",
        "e",
        "r",
        "t",
        "y",
        "u",
        "sfdgsdf",
        "gf",
        "gsd",
        "fgs",
        "dfg"});
        this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(170, 200);
        this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
        this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 95);
        this.listBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // timer1
        // 
        this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(570, 502);
        this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
}
```

Your form class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        removeItems();
        if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }

    void removeItems()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello from the removeMethod");
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }
}
```