# difference between Threading.Timer and Timer inside a thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

Is there any difference between

System.Threading.Timer

```
System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(PerformAction), null, 0, 15000);
```

and

using a System.Timers.Timer inside a new thread?

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PerformActionWithTimer));
thread.Start();

void PerformActionWithTimer()
{
   //Timer inside this
}
```

Comment: Maybe System.Windows.Forms.Timer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows.Forms.Timer OR System.Threading.Timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532850/windows-forms-timer-or-system-threading-timer)

Comment: Please explain "inside a new thread" what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a `System.Windows.Timer`.  Presumably you mean a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.  Don't ever try to use that class in a multi-threading scenario.  It raises its `Tick` event on the UI thread and that's it.  If you want a timer to raise events on a secondary thread then use a `System.Timers.Timer`.  There's no real reason to use the `System.Threading.Timer` directly at all.

Comment: I modified my question. I was about to ask this. by mistake i typed wrongly

Comment: I don't mean not to use a WinForms `Timer` in an application that uses multiple threads.  I mean don;t ever try to use a WinForms `Timer` where it needs to have knowledge of multiple threads.  As far as the WinForms `Timer` is concerned, there is only one thread: the UI thread.

Comment: Have you bothered to read the documentation?  "A Timer is used to raise an event at user-defined intervals. This Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where UI threads are used to perform processing. It requires that the user code have a UI message pump available and always operate from the same thread, or marshal the call onto another thread".  There's no ambiguity there.

Comment: Because there's an expectation of effort on your part here and if you haven't used the Help menu then you really haven't made what I would consider a satisfactory effort.

Answer (score 2):

I very strongly urge you *not* to use `System.Timers.Timer`, primarily due to this little bit of information from the Remarks section in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).

> The Timer component catches and suppresses all exceptions thrown by event handlers for the Elapsed event.

Which means that if your timer's elapsed event throws an exception that you don't explicitly catch, the exception will get swallowed and you'll never know that something bad happened.

Consider this `Elapsed` event handler:

```
static void MyTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Badness! Throwing exception");
    throw new ApplicationException("something bad happened");
}
```

Clearly, the intention here is to kill the program immediately because it encountered an unrecoverable error. But the exception will never escape to the main program. The timer handler in .NET does essentially this:

```
try
{
    MyTimer_Elapsed(sender, args);
}
catch
{
    // Why would anybody want to know that something bad happened?
}
```

It's a bug hider and as a result I won't use it.

In addition, there's no way to specify a context object that will be supplied in the event arguments, like there is with the Windows Forms timer (the `Tag` property) or `System.Threading.Timer` (the `state` parameter passed to the constructor).

`System.Timers.Timer` is a broken and limited component wrapper around `System.Threading.Timer`. Its two conveniences (the component wrapper and the `SynchronizingObject`) are far outweighed by its idiotic exception swallowing and the lack of a user context object. Don't use it. Use `System.Threading.Timer` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. The `System.Timers.Timer` has two modes of operation.

If `SynchronizingObject` is set to an `ISynchronizeInvoke` instance then the `Elapsed` event will execute on the thread hosting the synchronizing object. Usually these `ISynchronizeInvoke` instances are none other than plain old `Control` and `Form` instances that we are all familiar with. So in that case the `Elapsed` event is invoked on the UI thread and it behaves similar to the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. Otherwise, it really depends on the specific `ISynchronizeInvoke` instance that was used.

If `SynchronizingObject` is null then the `Elapsed` event is invoked on a `ThreadPool` thread and it behaves similar to the `System.Threading.Timer`. In fact, it actually uses a `System.Threading.Timer` behind the scenes and does the marshaling operation after it receives the timer callback if needed.

In your specific case the `System.Timers.Timer` that you have created does not have a synchronizing object assigned so it will behave the same as a `System.Threading.Timer`.