# How do i use thread locks in an infinite loop?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am fairly new to threading in general and i want to try it in C#. I am trying to make a basic simulation of tonnage of something which is decaying every 20 seconds and being refilled every 10 seconds. From what i read, thread safety is something i need to consider as there are two threads; one for decaying the variable tonnage by 160, one for adding a random amount to the tonnage and since they are making transactions to the variable **tonnage**, i should make sure they are accessed correctly.

I read on how to use **lock(object)** and i understand the concept for simple thread examples but how do i use it for 2 threads running forever and have to make timely adjustments in the tonnage?

Here is what i have, but when i lock the whole loop, the other thread never spawns. Or do i have the wrong code structure?

```
public double tonnage = 1000;
private object x = new object(); 

//Starts the simulation, runs forever until user ends the simulation
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Decay Tonnage
    Thread decayTonnageThread = new Thread(() => decayTonnage (tonnage));
    decayTonnageThread .Start();

    //Add Tonnage
    Thread addTonnageThread = new Thread(() => addTonnage (tonnage));
    addTonnageThread .Start();
}

//I want to decay the tonnage every 20 seconds
public void decayTonnage (double tonnage)
    {
        lock(x)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                tonnage = tonnage - 160;
                Thread.Sleep(20000);
            }
        }
    }

//Add to the tonnage every 10 seconds
public void addTonnage (double tonnage)
    {
        lock(x)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                double randomNumber = random.Next(97, 102);
                tonnage = tonnage + randomNumber;
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll want to do your locking inside the loops, not outside.

Comment: Use lock only when changing tonnage, exclude the rest of the code. Maybe using the [Interlocked class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx) could be a good idea

Comment: @adv12 it worked thanks!

Comment: @Jeroen if you are using `lock` it is not nessesary, `lock` introduces a full memory fence so it should be safe to read the value of `tonnage`.

Comment: @Jeroen I will look at the Interlocked class as well. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the lock to be as small as possible, only have it around the lines that are interacting with shared objects, not the entire loop. Also, putting `Random random = new Random();` in the while loop [is a bad habit to have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number), you should make only one random instance and initialize it outside of the loop.

```
//I want to decay the tonnage every 20 seconds
public void decayTonnage (double tonnage)
{

        while (true)
        {
            lock(x)
            {
                tonnage = tonnage - 160;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
        }
}

//Add to the tonnage every 10 seconds
public void addTonnage (double tonnage)
{

        Random random = new Random();
        while (true)
        {
            double randomNumber = random.Next(97, 102);
            lock(x)
            {
                tonnage = tonnage + randomNumber;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
}
```

Also, I assume you are doing this for some kind of assignment and must use threads, but if I was doing this for real I would not use threads with loops + a `Sleep` at all and instead use two timers, one that fired every 20 seconds and one that fired every 10 seconds. Depending on the [type of timer you use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532850/windows-forms-timer-or-system-threading-timer) you may or may-not still need to use a lock.

Comment: I will try this and yes i see it makes sense to lock only the lines interacting with shared objects. It is not for an assignment, its for work (not in production yet). I am trying to model a simulation of what would happen if the user changed a few variables so i went with threading. I will look into your suggestion in using timers, thank you.