# C# - Winforms - Repeating method with help of timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I recently started learning C#, I am trying to repeat a method every minute with help of a timer. The method changes the value of the label. However, I get the following error:

> $exception    {"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label1'
>   accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created
>   on."} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

I have tried searching for a solution and each thread confuses me. I don't just need the correct code but also explanation as I want to learn manipulating UI with help of Timers and Threading.

The following is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;



namespace Winforms_Timer_and_Thread
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        public Form1()
        {
            myTimer.Enabled = true;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void startMethod(object senter, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            int cntr = 0;
            cntr++;
            label1.Text = "Executed: " + cntr.ToString();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Started!";
            myTimer.Enabled = true;
            myTimer.Interval=(1*60*1000);
            myTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(startMethod);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c
You can't access UI directly from non-ui thread.

Comment: You might also consider using a System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead.

Comment: @James R. But then is it possible to call the method every minute?

Comment: @Tango - Yes, but it's a very different kind of mechanism. It doesn't really involve multiple threads. Under the covers, Windows will send a WM_TIMER message to the HWND of your form on the interval given. At least that's how I suspect it's implemented.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532859/11683

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change to use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, you won't have that problem, since it's executed in the same UI thread.

You only have to change:

- The type of the timer from `System.Timers.Timer` to `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`
- The event that gets subscribed to from `Elapsed` to `Tick`
- The event signature, where `ElapsedEventArgs e` becomes `EventArgs e`

You also only need to subscribe to the event once, not each time the timer is enabled, so move that to the `Form_Load` event instead, along with the `Interval` assignment (although that can be changed any time).

You also might want to store the counter variable outside of the `StartMethod`, so it increments each time it's executed, and then reset it to zero each time you start the timer:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    readonly System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    private int tickCounter;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myTimer.Interval = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds;
        myTimer.Tick += StartMethod;
    }

    private void StartMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tickCounter++;
        label1.Text = "Number of executions: " + tickCounter;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tickCounter = 0;
        label1.Text = "Started!";
        myTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```