# How to log data in C# accurately at 10ms from an embedded device?

Tags: c#, console-application, compact-framework, .net-framework-version

I want to read/sample the data from an embedded device accurately at periodic intervals of 10ms in C# console application. What is the best way to log the data accurately at every 10ms interval.

I tried with System.Timers and Threading Timer but I am able to log fewer data points than required. I am developing my console application in .NET Compact framework 3.5.

What is the best way to log the data accurately at such lower intervals?

I am facing issue with no. of data points. It should be same for fixed interval of time, but it varies with +/- 1 data point.
I am using stopwatch class.

Comment: Depends on what the word "accurate" means to you. C# will never be able to run code at an exact point in time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532850/windows-forms-timer-or-system-threading-timer/4532859#4532859

Comment: So your problem is that sometimes the timer fires slightly later than at other times? That's expected. If you're receiving a data point every 10ms, then why is that a problem? Just plot as many data point as you have received.

Comment: Presumably you are on special hardware when you are using the compact framework so are you even sure that hardware can log that fast?

Comment: @Franck I want to sample the data at fixed intervals say 100ms. In this case once my code receives a start trigger, I should be able to execute a function which is called every 100ms. In case of System. Timers average execution time for one interval is about 110ms, same is applicable for Threading timer too. If I log more than samples in this case once my stop trigger is received there is a chance that I get less no. of data points than required one because of that extra 10ms shift.

Comment: @canton7 No. of data points are very important to me as my production part might get rejected if one data point is not present. If I want to log data at 100ms for 1 second, then I should be able to get exactly 10 data points every time I run the code. Sometimes I get 9 or 8 which is not acceptable.

Comment: @Ralf I really don't have that idea !